# Cannot declare a templated type alias in a function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to do

```
template <typename N>
using Array = std::array<std::uint8_t, N>;
```

Within a function, but clang spits out an error: *expected expression.*

For example

```
void func()
{
    template <typename T>
    using Vec = std:vector<T>;
}
```

will result in this error.

Is this not allowed in functions and if so why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias#Explanation) could only be declared at class scope or namespace scope.

> Like any template declaration, an alias template can only be declared at class scope or namespace scope.

BTW: You should declare a [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) for your alias template `Array`, e.g.

```
template <std::size_t N>
using Array = std::array<std::uint8_t, N>;
```

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I missed that. Is there any specific rationale behind this?

Comment: @Matthew Alias template is considered to be templates too; it follows the rule of them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this not allowed in functions and if so why?

Yup. Because the C++ standard explicitly prohibits it for all templates. [[temp]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#2) says:

> A *template-declaration* can appear only as a namespace scope or class
>   scope declaration.

The rationale is probably to not make the already fragile template specification more susceptible to ODR violations. Even now, the order of appearance for specializations can make programs ill-formed or well-formed somewhat unexpectedly.

The crux of the matter is that we don't really need function scope templates, IMO.